# AKSequencer with Ableton Link

Tags: audiokit, ableton-live, aksequencer

Has anyone did synchronization AKSequencer with Ableton Link accurately?
Whatever I do, it not synchronized at all.

I take beatTime from AbletonLink and play sequencer at this position + output latency. Since the delay between function play called and actual playing is unpredictable, it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't use the AKSequencer (which is based on Apple's sequencer and therefore mostly closed source) for our synths that need a sequencer because of this unpredictability.  Instead we use AKTimeline based solutions such as in the metronome example in AudioKit:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/Examples/iOS/MetronomeSamplerSync