# Which route to reliable midi sequencing in Audiokit 4.9.3?

Tags: swift, audiokit

Looking to sequence with Audiokit 4.9.3 in Swift and ultimately would like to implement Ableton Link so I came across this post:

[AKSequencer with Ableton Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422301/aksequencer-with-ableton-link)

When I look at the linked example in that answer I don't see the use of AKTimeline, the example seems to rely on AVAudioTime. AKTimelineTap sounds very interesting but hasn't made the docs yet.  Additionally AKSequencer has been replaced since that question was answered.

So...

What is the currently recommended accurate sequencing solution and is there an example for getting it running?

Thanks for any input and thanks too for AudioKit, it's got my app spitting out great melodies in just a couple of days.

**Update:** I've got AKSequencer up and running nicely for my purposes so far. No attempt yet to use Link. It seems at least as good as an old test I did with old AKSequencer (now AKAppleSequencer). When I get to Link I'll explore the other options further and hopefully uncover some more AKTimeline and AKTimelineTap discoveries...